# How to find the most frequent element in a list, but in case of draws return the one with last index

Tags: python, arrays, arr

Similar question was posted but I do not know how to return one with the last index.
The part where I try to solve the problem is in the function pop() up to b = max(...)

```
import itertools
import operator
class FreqStack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.STACK = []
        self.output = []
    def push(self, val: int) -> None:
        self.STACK.append(val)
    def pop(self) -> int:
        SL = sorted((x, i) for i, x in enumerate(self.STACK))
        groups = itertools.groupby(SL, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
        def _auxfun(g):
            item, iterable = g
            count = 0
            min_index = len(self.STACK)
            for _, where in iterable:
                count += 1
                min_index = min(min_index, where)
            return count, -min_index
          # pick the highest-count/earliest item
        b = max(groups, key=_auxfun)[0]
        self.STACK.reverse()
        try:
            self.STACK.remove(b)
        except:
            pass
        self.STACK.reverse()
        return b
```

Comment: Can you add an example having several calls to `push` and `pop` illustrating what is expected output for some difficult cases?

Comment: Well that was no success...